# My q-btn elements are not rendering appropriately in Quasar

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, sass, quasar-framework

I am new to Quasar and I don't know why, but my `q-btn` component buttons render as white backgrounds sometimes, ignoring the `background-color` I added to them, using external stylesheets.

The following are examples of this baffling problem

[image]

The above button should look like below

[image]

Another example is

[image]

The above one should look like

[image]

The buttons render properly some times, but just like that, without any clear pattern, they render with the white backgrounds.

It was suggested that the reason this was happening is because the buttons are being rendered before the external scss files are parsed. I changed the style of importing external scss files from

```html
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
  import './_custom-style.scss // initial import style
  ...
</script>
```

to

```html
<template>
 ...
</template>

<script>
 ...
</script>

<style lang="scss" src="./_custom-style.scss"></style> // new css import style
```

This didn't work.

It was suggested that I use `q-btn's` `color` prop, (which is less than ideal, because I won't be able to use a custom hex color for my background), however I tried adding the color prop to it, using one of quasar's colors (in the color palette) and it still isn't rendering appropriately all the time. I don't know what else to do.

EDIT:

These are the scss file and one of the templates that use the `q-btn` component.

```css
airtime {
  ...
  &__redeem-btn {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 80%;
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: $purple-dark-3;
    color: $primary-white;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="airtime text-center">
    <h1 class="..">Congratulations!</h1>
    <p class="..">You got <strong>7</strong> questions correct</p>

    <q-img
      src="icons/...svg"
      transition="fade"
      class=".."
      alt=".."
    />
    <p class=".."></p>
    <q-btn
      class="airtime__redeem-btn" 
      rounded 
      label="Redeem" 
      no-caps
      @click="$emit('selectNetworkProvider')"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the error. It turns out that there was a clashing style in my application

```css
.q-btn__wrapper {
  background-color: $primary-white;
}
```

This style overrode the `background-color` of the `q-btn` components.